# Unable to POST, PUT or DELETE resource with flask when setting up https using nginx and gunicorn

Tags: flask, https, ssl-certificate, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have build a flask API.

When using it in dev environment like this : `http://www.apiexample.com:5000`, it works.

But once I set up prod environment using `Nginx`, `Gunicorn` with a trusted SSL certificate (and thus port `443`), I can't do `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` request anymore, I can do only `GET` request.

Here is what is shown when I try to send any form.
[image]

Is it a matter of certificate or `nginx/gunicorn` server setup?

Answer (score 0):

I found and fix the issue.

In fact, during redirects my flask application was losing the https and redirect to http instead, cause it was not getting `X-Forwarded` headers from ngninx.

Here is what I added to my `nginx` configuration :

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```